# Is filevault compatible with LDAP configurations?

Tags: filevault, ldap

I turned on FileVault (on my Enterprise attached Mac) and it's no longer prompting me for my LDAP credentials.  After the filevault login, it just tosses me straight into local administrator.  LDAP still shows as on and "working", but does not appear to be.

My old Mac (with an old OS) used to ask me for the admin filevault password, followed by my LDAP password, and then continue on by logging into the appropriate LDAP user account.

Have I missed some configuration step on the new Mac, or has there been a change in how the newest OS X handle filevault+LDAP?

Comment: Did you already check [this](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2300563&seqNum=9) article?

Comment: No, I'd not stumbled across that article.  This is an Active Directory environment.  Any ideas on how I would adjust it to work properly with the Apple expected behavior?

Comment: Your Mac is in an AD environment?

Comment: Correct.  We're a 95% Windows environment with a handful of Linux and Mac boxes, so we authenticate those against AD (which is basically a fancy LDAP server, so we configure everything just like normal LDAP on the *nix side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get FileVault to work in an Enterprise configuration of OS X.  So, I'll answer this as "not currently possible".  Perhaps some later update of OS X...